# netbeans multiple definition; first defined in _nomain.o error on building C++ simple test

Tags: c++, testing, netbeans

I've created three C++ simple tests in `tests` folder in my projects directory. When I created the first C++ simple test and built it there was no problem but when I create the second or third, innumerable errors listed below are generated

```
build/DebugDynamic/GNU-Linux-x86/ClientSocket.o: In function `Socket::is_valid() const':
/home/gowtham/workspace/base/ClientSocket.cpp:8: multiple definition of `ClientSocket::ClientSocket(std::string, int, Socket::SOCKET_TYPE, std::string, std::string, std::string)'
build/DebugDynamic/GNU-Linux-x86/ClientSocket_nomain.o:/home/gowtham/workspace/base/ClientSocket.cpp:8: first defined here
```

The linker command is

```
g++ -g -O0      -o build/DebugDynamic/GNU-Linux-x86/tests/TestFiles/f3 build/DebugDynamic/GNU-Linux-x86/tests/tests/sizeInfo.o build/DebugDynamic/GNU-Linux-x86/ClientSocket_nomain.o build/DebugDynamic/GNU-Linux-x86/FFJSON_nomain.o build/DebugDynamic/GNU-Linux-x86/JPEGImage_nomain.o build/DebugDynamic/GNU-Linux-x86/ServerSocket_nomain.o build/DebugDynamic/GNU-Linux-x86/Socket_nomain.o build/DebugDynamic/GNU-Linux-x86/logger_nomain.o build/DebugDynamic/GNU-Linux-x86/myconverters_nomain.o build/DebugDynamic/GNU-Linux-x86/mycurl_nomain.o build/DebugDynamic/GNU-Linux-x86/mystdlib_nomain.o build/DebugDynamic/GNU-Linux-x86/myxml_nomain.o build/DebugDynamic/GNU-Linux-x86/ClientSocket.o build/DebugDynamic/GNU-Linux-x86/FFJSON.o build/DebugDynamic/GNU-Linux-x86/JPEGImage.o build/DebugDynamic/GNU-Linux-x86/ServerSocket.o build/DebugDynamic/GNU-Linux-x86/Socket.o build/DebugDynamic/GNU-Linux-x86/logger.o build/DebugDynamic/GNU-Linux-x86/myconverters.o build/DebugDynamic/GNU-Linux-x86/mycurl.o build/DebugDynamic/GNU-Linux-x86/mystdlib.o build/DebugDynamic/GNU-Linux-x86/myxml.o -lxml2 -lpthread -lssl -lcrypto -lz
```

netbeans is including a duplicate object file `_nomain.o` for every object file in the project.

**ClientSocket.h**

```
#ifndef CLIENTSOCKET_H
#define CLIENTSOCKET_H

#include "Socket.h"

class ClientSocket : public Socket {
public:

    class AftermathObj {
    public:
        void* (*aftermath)(void* aftermathDS, bool isSuccess);
        void* aftermathDS;
        std::string payload;
        std::string* payloadPTR;
        std::string error;
        int __flags;
        pthread_t t;
        ClientSocket* cs;

        AftermathObj() {
        };

        ~AftermathObj() {
        };
    };

    ClientSocket();
    ClientSocket(std::string host, int port, Socket::SOCKET_TYPE socketType = Socket::DEFAULT, std::string trustedCA = "", std::string privatecert = "", std::string privatekey = "");
    std::string host;
    int port;
    void reconnect();
    void disconnect();
    bool send(const std::string s, int __flags) const;
    bool send(const std::string* s, int __flags) const;
    bool send(const std::string s) const;
    virtual ~ClientSocket();
    const ClientSocket& operator <<(const std::string&) const;
    void asyncsend(std::string payload, AftermathObj* after_math_obj);
    void asyncsend(std::string* payload, AftermathObj* aftermath_obj);
    const ClientSocket& operator >>(std::string&) const;


private:
    //Socket* soc;
    static void* socsend(void*);

    struct soc_send_t_args {
        std::string s;
        void* (&aftermath)(void* aftermathDS);
        void* aftermathDS;
    };
    pthread_key_t socket_thread_key;
};


#endif
```

Comment: Can you please show the actual code for this? Especially the header file. Because I guess you define the function in the header file but outside the class, instead of inside the class or in a single source file.

Comment: I added the header file. I think its a bug.

Comment: Then you define the same function in both source files. If they are separate programs that should be separate, then don't link the object file together. If the files are *supposed* to be linked together, then you can only have the definitions in one of them.

Comment: netbeans automates the linking. Did you observe the linker command generated by the netbeans above? its linking a duplicate _nomain.o file for every object file in the project.